# Query mongodb secondary node stuck through java-client after restart mongo router

Tags: mongodb, networking, mongodb-query, mongodb-java, replicaset

I have a shard cluster on 5 server with 5 shards, each shard is a replica set with 1 primary node and 2 secondary nodes. MongoDB 3.4.5 on Linux RHEL7.2.

Hostname for 5 servers are dscn022 - dscn026

The cluster worked well for a week, then this occured in the config server's log

```
> Tue Feb  6 15:37:28.904 I NETWORK  [thread2] Listener: accept() returns -1 Too many open files

>Tue Feb  6 15:37:28.905 E NETWORK  [thread2] Out of file descriptors. Waiting one second before trying to accept more connections.
```

Then I checked the ulimit, is it possible that mongoDB use that much?

```
>[root@dscn022 ~]# ulimit -a

> open files                      (-n) 655360
```

And after that file descriptors thing repeated for about 40 times, other errors logs happend.

```
> Tue Feb  6 15:38:10.360 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Connecting to dscn023:27018

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:10.360 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Failed to connect to dscn023:27018 - HostUnreachable: HostUnreachable

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:10.360 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Dropping all pooled connections to dscn023:27018 due to failed operation on a connection

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:10.360 I NETWORK  [replSetDistLockPinger] Marking host dscn023:27018 as failed :: caused by :: HostUnreachable: HostUnreachable

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:10.360 W SHARDING [replSetDistLockPinger] pinging failed for distributed lock pinger :: caused by :: HostUnreachable: HostUnreachable

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:10.914 I NETWORK  [thread2] connection accepted from 10.11.2.24:34192 #1680 (116 connections now open)

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:10.915 I NETWORK  [conn1680] received client metadata from 10.11.2.24:34192 conn1680: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "unknown" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_73-b02" }

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:10.920 I NETWORK  [conn1680] Successfully connected to TOD-Shard-1/dscn022:27019,dscn023:27019,dscn026:27019 (65 connections now open to TOD-Shard-1/dscn022:27019,dscn023:27019,dscn026:27019 with a 0 second timeout)

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:10.920 I NETWORK  [conn1680] getaddrinfo("dscn022") failed: No address associated with hostname

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:10.920 I NETWORK  [conn1680] Marking host dscn022:27019 as failed :: caused by :: Location40333: can't connect to new replica set master [dscn022:27019], err: couldn't initialize connection to host dscn022, address is invalid

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:10.921 I NETWORK  [conn1680] getaddrinfo("dscn023") failed: No address associated with hostname

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:10.921 I NETWORK  [conn1680] Marking host dscn023:27019 as failed :: caused by :: Location11002: can't callLazy replica set node dscn023:27019: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for dscn023:27019

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:10.921 I NETWORK  [conn1680] getaddrinfo("dscn026") failed: No address associated with hostname

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:10.921 I NETWORK  [conn1680] Marking host dscn026:27019 as failed :: caused by :: Location11002: can't callLazy replica set node dscn026:27019: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for dscn026:27019

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:10.921 I NETWORK  [conn1680] getaddrinfo("dscn022") failed: No address associated with hostname

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:10.921 I NETWORK  [conn1680] Marking host dscn022:27019 as failed :: caused by :: Location40333: can't connect to new replica set master [dscn022:27019], err: couldn't initialize connection to host dscn022, address is invalid

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:10.921 W NETWORK  [conn1680] db exception when initializing on TOD-Shard-1, current connection state is { state: { conn: "TOD-Shard-1/dscn022:27019,dscn023:27019,dscn026:27019", vinfo: "expressbox.box @ 5|2326||5a7423d5a8007256eb0d6914", cursor: "(empty)", count: 0, done: false }, retryNext: false, init: false, finish: false, errored: false } :: caused by :: 16380 Failed to call say, no good nodes in TOD-Shard-1, last error: can't callLazy replica set node dscn022:27019: can't connect to new replica set master [dscn022:27019], err: couldn't initialize connection to host dscn022, address is invalid

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:10.921 I NETWORK  [conn1680] Ending connection to host TOD-Shard-1/dscn022:27019,dscn023:27019,dscn026:27019(with timeout of 0 seconds) due to bad connection status; 64 connections to that host remain open

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:15.103 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Connecting to dscn024:27018

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:15.105 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Failed to connect to dscn024:27018 - HostUnreachable: HostUnreachable

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:15.105 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Dropping all pooled connections to dscn024:27018 due to failed operation on a connection

> Tue Feb  6 15:38:31.997 I ACCESS   [UserCacheInvalidator] User cache generation changed from 5a7418c44db54c97a8335650 to 5a7418c67d14edfa21ed4f3d; invalidating user cache
```

It seems that config server cannot find all the hostname even the hostname of itself.

After I restart the router and the config server, the cluster seems ok, all functions are good, but my application cannot query through java-driver using read concern "Secondary" or "SecondaryPreferred".

Using Primary or PrimaryPreferred works querying shard collection, and all read concern works querying non-shard collection.

The same situation happened 2 weeks ago, I rebuild the cluster and now it happens again.

Why is it happening and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Hi Brian, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't be alarmed, but I've flagged your question as really belonging on another part of the site (dba.stackexchange.com) because it's about database operations/maintenance, and not about programming as such.

Comment: There is a networking issue from MongoD's persepective:  "getaddrinfo("dscn022") failed: No address associated with hostname".  It is unable to connect.  The Java driver checks the state of the cluster and will direct reads as per the readPreference. It does require a healthy cluster.